# How to make functional tests that require to be authenticated, in Symfony 2?

Tags: php, testing, symfony

I couldn't find any documentation about this.

I'm using the client object to send a request to /login, fill the form, and submit it. That works fine, but I'm getting a 302 response back to /login, as if the credentials were incorrect.

In any case, I think there should be at least one row in the sessions table after the first request, but there isn't any. How is that possible?

Any thoughts?

Edit: Here's the code:

```
    // Go to login page
    $client = $this->createClient();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/login');
    $this->assertTrue($crawler->filter('html:contains("Username")')->count() > 0);

    // Fill in the form and submit it
    $form = $crawler->selectButton('login')->form();
    $form['_username'] = 'admin';
    $form['_password'] = 'admin';
    $client->submit($form);
    $this->assertEquals(302,$client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
    $this->assertFalse($client->getResponse()->isRedirect('http://localhost/login'));
```

The last assert fails

Comment: can u show the part of the code that runs this test?

Comment: @Ibu sure, there you are

Comment: have You eventually succeeded with this test? I know it's a long shot assuming that You will remember, but maybe... ?

Answer (score 2):

You should create a new firewal using http basic authentication:

```
security:
    ...
    firewalls:
        functional_test:
            pattern: /secure/.*
            stateless: true
            http_basic:
                provider: provider_name
    ...
```

Then create a client like this:

```
$client = $this->createClient(array(), array(
    'PHP_AUTH_USER' => 'username',
    'PHP_AUTH_PW' => 'password',
));
```

Happy coding !

Answer (score 0):

Not to far official documentation include article [How to simulate Authentication with a Token in a Functional Test](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/simulating_authentication.html). May be it helps someone.